# Диалоговое окно в MFC

Tags: mfc, dialog

У меня есть основное приложение, на котором находится Button. При нажатии открывается диалоговое окно. На данном окне добавил Edit и Button, при нажатии кнопки поле Edit не заполняется. Если же выполнить данную операцию в окне основного приложения, всё работает отлично. В чём дело?

Открываю окно.

```
CDialog dlg(IDD_DIALOG1);
dlg.DoModal();
```

Обработка кнопки.

```
m_text = "OK";
UpdateData(0);
```

Comment: Ошибка где-то в обработчике нажатия на кнопку (который надо было приводить в вопросе).

Comment: @VTT Так в основном приложении при таком же обработчике работает всё хорошо!

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). что такое `m_text`? Что такое `UpdateData`?

Comment: @VTT m_text переменная поля Edit, задана как CString. UpdateData функция обновления данных окна.